# lambda function subscribing to sns fifo topic

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sns, fifo

I need to trigger an AWS lambda function with events from an SNS fifo topic. Seams that is not possible, any ideas to make that connection happen?

thank you in advance

Comment: This may help https://acloudguru.com/blog/engineering/event-driven-architecture-with-sqs-and-aws-lambda

Comment: Or here is amazon docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns.html

Comment: I was able to trigger the function with SNS without issues (standard SNS). the problem was with SNS fifo.

Answer (score 4):

We had the same issue.
Our solution was to create an SQS fifo, subscribe it to the SNS fifo, and use the SQS fifo as the lambda trigger.

Comment: Same here. Just to support this solution with additional information:
Lambda doesn't support yet SNS FIFO triggering events, only standard SNS, but supports SQS FIFO and this is currently the way you can go: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/fifo-message-delivery.html. 
So if you want to use SNS FIFO you need to introduce SNS Fanout to SQS FIFO then use that SQS FIFO topic to trigger lambda.